# How to output an environment variable with TWIG into a form input value

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

When I attempt to capture the template name in a form input value parameter it results in an empty value. I'm hoping this is just because I need to escape something. Outputting this.page.id in the body outside of an input tag works fine, and even inside of the tag as long as I'm not setting equal to the value it outputs correctly. How do I get the value to equal the output of the page name?

[image]

```
<form id="fcia_gen-contact_form" class="row" data-form-redirect="application/" data-form-type="core-4-redirect">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="first" class="col-md-12">
    <label>First Name</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="last" class="col-md-12">
    <label>Last Name</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="col-md-12">
    <label>Email</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="col-md-12">
    <label>Phone Number</label>
</div>

    {{ this.page.id }}

    <input type="hidden" name="Page_Type" value="{{ template_type }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Page" value="{{ this.page.id }}">
</form>
```

update: It looks like it's the equal sign causing this.

[image]

I've also tried string interpolation, which results in the same:
`<input type="hidden" name="Page" {{ "value=\"#{this.page.id}\"" }}>`

Comment: Does your variable contains quotes ?

Comment: This isn't my variable, it's an environmental variable from October CMS and no it's only a page name.

Comment: If you can't change the variable then try to clean it `{{ this.page.id | replace({ '"': '', }) | trim }}`

Comment: That did it, thanks you!